# Use Font for S7735R LCD using ESP32

Tags: c, fonts, embedded, esp32

I'm working on ESP32. With ESP32 MCU interface S7735 LCD and I'm use  ESP_IDF as an IDE.

I use " https://github.com/loboris/ESP32_TFT_library " for TFT_LCD and there are given fonts I use.I'm tried given font and its working fine and if you want to use your custom font then simply put font file in spiffs/fonts folder and flash into the ESP32.

Above this steps I follow but not reflect any font style if I flash custom font in .ttf . I also try to convert .ttf to .fon font but .fon format is for Window/Dos. and for LCD I need a .fon (binary).

I did not get which font extension I use for this given particular file. Kindly suggest compatible font extension and link also where I will be download easily.

```
static const char *file_fonts[3] = {"/spiffs/fonts/DotMatrix_M.fon", "/spiffs/fonts/Ubuntu.fon", "/spiffs/fonts/Grotesk24x48.fon"};
```

from main/tft_demo.c there are given above line and that font use from given path.

I need a solution for font file which is compatible with my driver.
Kindly suggest me flow for new custom font use.

Comment: It sounds you probably want to ask this on https://github.com/loboris/ESP32_TFT_library/issues at the very least, since they are the authority on which format you need to use and what the spec for that format is. The documentation is there (in the /tools dir as noted by Clifford), but it's kind of hidden so you probably want to file an issue asking them to add a section to the main readme that explains that it exists, and why you'd want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The font format is proprietary and simple bit-maps.  The file name extension .fon is generic and tells you nothing about the actual format.

The `/tools` folder of the library you linked includes a tool for converting TTF fonts to bitmaps generated as C code data arrays that you simply link to your project to add fonts.

From the read-me file:

> Program to convert any ttf font to c source file that can be includes
>   in ESP32 tft library.
>
> This is a windows program, but can be used under Linux with wine:
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> ttf2c_vc2003.exe <point-size> <input-file> <output-file> [<start_char> <end_char>]
> ```
>
> or, under Linux:
>
> ```
> wine ./ttf2c_vc2003.exe <point-size> <input-file> <output-file> [<start_char> <end_char>]
> ```

There is more in the read-me file - a couple of manual edits that need to be made.  The folder includes examples for Vera and DejaVu Sans.

Comment: I'm a senior engineer and don't expect subdirs to have their own README unless linked from the main document, which this one isn't. It's very nice that it's there, but holding someone to account for not finding a hidden readme feels questionable at best. We don't grep repos for readme*.* after reading the (comprehensive, in this case) main documentation ;)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't disagree, but when using a third party library, I would perhaps survey the package contents, and this was only one level deep amongst a small number of folders. I have never used or encountered this library prior to this question; it took me about 30 seconds of browsing to spot it. Whilst you may have a valid point about documentation, if you choose to rely on free/open source software, you have to accept that the quality will vary. I suspect the font generator in this case is perhaps "donated" from a separate project.